# Use same instance of socket across React application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sockets, socket.io

The goal is to initiate a socket connection in App.js on app start and then make this exact socket instance available to other components that are loaded with Router. Online research suggests passing socket to a nested component as follows:

```
const socket = io();
...
render() {
return(<div className="App"><NestedComponent socket={socket} /></div>)
}
```

This does not work if socket is passed via Router

```
<Route path='/somepath' socket={socket} component={SomeComponent}/>
```

If I attempt using socket in SomeComponent (e.g.: `this.props.socket.emit('hi', {})`), this breaks app as socket turns out to be undefined in SomeComponent.

I was not able to look up a working solution to either pass same instance of a socket with a Router, or use Redux to make socket part of the app state and provide it to lower level components.

Any input on this is much appreciated.

Comment: If this socket is a singleton, can't you just import it? If you must really unit test it, you could mock it. Otherwise, why not use the context API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use render method and pass the socket like this:

```
<Route path='/somepath' 
  render={(props) => (<SomeComponent socket={socket} {...props} />)} />
```

Notice: `{...props}` is being passed to access router props like location, history, match etc.

In SomeComponent:

```
// to access socket props
this.props.socket
```

So, this should work fine now:

```
this.props.socket.emit('hi', {})
```

Comment: You're awesome! Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm doing the exact same thing but when I try access props.socket (using hooks) it says props.socket is undefined